# Compile error OSX

Tags: macos, compilation

I'm trying to compile a program called [PEAR](https://github.com/xflouris/PEAR) and it seems there is something wrong at this step.

I have Xcode installed.

```
Bernardos-MacBook-Pro:pear-0.9.0-src bernardo$ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C src all
gcc -c -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -lm pear-pt.c -o pear-pt.o
clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused
gcc -c -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -lm reader.c -o reader.o
clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused
reader.c:670:1: warning: unused function 'do_cpuid' [-Wunused-function]
do_cpuid(uint32_t selector, uint32_t *data)
^
1 warning generated.
gcc -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -lm pear-pt.o args.o statistics.o reader.o -lm -lpthread -o pear
ld: warning: ignoring file args.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): args.o
ld: warning: ignoring file statistics.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): statistics.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_decode_switches", referenced from:
      _main in pear-pt.o
  "_stat_test2", referenced from:
      _assembly_FORWARD_LONGER in pear-pt.o
      _assembly_READS_EQUAL in pear-pt.o
      _assembly_REVERSE_LONGER in pear-pt.o
      _assembly in pear-pt.o
  "_usage", referenced from:
      _main in pear-pt.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [pear] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You are missing a library or two and looking at the warnings about the use of `-l` at the same time as `-c`, it looks like that `Makefile` is broken.

Comment: Also missing comp;lie of args.o and statistics.o

Comment: So, the solutions would be to install those libraries?